# Express route handling / req.body empty on some routes

Tags: angularjs, express

I have two routes. Before each request, there should fire a method:

```
app.all('*',function(req,res,next){
    console.dir(req.body);
    // Some more stuff
});
```

I make a `POST` call to my first route:

> $http.post('/users/login',{
>               alias: $scope.alias,
>               password: $scope.password
>           });

Everything works just fine, Express logs to the credentials to the console.

I call another route:

> $http.post('/shipments/delete',{
>               alias: '11',
>               password: '22'
>           })

Express logs an empty Object.

WTH is happening here?

Comment: I assume you're using `bodyParser()` or (hopefully) `urlencoded()` to parse the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a DIFFERENT route is matching the POST to `/users/login`. Express routing is about matching request paths to handler functions. You have to post all of the relevant route paths and handler functions for us to show you your mistake, and if you're not confident you can determine which are relevant, post them ALL.  But really you probably don't want to be using `app.all('*'` ever. Learn about middleware: `app.use(` instead because these two work slightly differently, with middleware being generally more correct/useful.

Comment: Same issue when using app.use