# Unable to POST values to Express in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning to use Express (v4) in Node.js. I'm building a basic REST api. My api has one endpoint: /orders. I want to be able to get a list of orders and POST new orders. To do this, I've defined the following routes:

```
app.get('/orders', myApi.getOrders);
app.post('/orders', myApi.createOrder);
```

I can successfully call these routes via Postman. However, when I attempt to POST values to create an order, my data isn't there. I've noticed that I can read the data the request headers values. However, I can't read any of the key/values set in the form-data. I'm trying to read my request using the following:

```
createOrder: function(req, res) {
  try {
    console.log(req);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
};
```

Nothing fancy. I don't understand why the headers are there. However, the form-data isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you set your "Postman" to send application/json as Content-Type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: @daniel - Do I need to explicity set the content-type? Is that a header variable? Thank you!

Comment: Some REST clients send your payload as form-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Postman currently does not explicitly send a Content-Type with forms, so you need to make sure to manually set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for your request.

Also make sure you have the `body-parser` or some other middleware capable of parsing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` loaded before those routes in your stack.