# Nodejs- Req.body undefined in post with express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

I am using a middleware `body-parser` to encoded the form values to get in req.body object.
But as I debug my code, found out req.body is undefined. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Listen Post request

```
app.post('/newCategory', function (req,res) {

            //express attached the form encoded values into body
            var categoryName = req.body.categoryName;
        });
```

Html Form

```
<form action="/newCategory" role="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="categoryName" placeholder="Category name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" value="New Category" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Answer (score 12):

Just ran into the same issue. It looks like I resolved my problem by moving my code to map routes after the urlencoded line. I am now seeing req.body in the post.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// Map routes
var controllers = require("./controllers");
controllers.init(app);
```

Comment: Here is somewhat similar answer in a somewhat similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/a/13779626/788833

Answer (score 7):

This solved the problem for me

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Hope this help

Comment: If only I had stumbled upon your solution 2 hours earlier, I could have had a good night sleep. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that the order is very important. Usually the router should be declared in the end before starting the server .
Eg: 
1.i import the required files

```
var express            = require("express");
var bodyParser         = require("body-parser");
var morgan             = require("morgan");
var db              = require("./db.js");

var app                = express();
```

2.i declare the other stuffs

```
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev') ); // Log every request to console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

3. AFTER I INCLUDE ROUTES - most important step

```
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
routes(app);   //routes shall use Express
```

4. start the server

   app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
       console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get("port"));
   });

And then will work .. i'm not sure why but after it happen few time i learn the lesson .

Answer (score 2):

If you're using urlencoded with `{ extended:false }`, `req.body` will return the unparsed raw string from the form `categoryName=test`. Meaning `req.body.categoryName` will be undefined.

Try passing true so it can parse the form data using the qs module.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Comment: I tried both but I am getting req.body undefined. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As body-parser module is used to parse the body and urls, it should be called before any call to "req.body..."

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
///////req.body is undefined here
//extended: false means you are parsing strings only (not parsing images/videos..etc)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
///////you req.body is working here (module below is using req.body)
app.use("/", module);
app.post('/newCategory', function (req,res) {
     var categoryName = req.body.categoryName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am use this:

`const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());`
but verify if your POSTMAN, for he can be the problem