# Express request body for post is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following setup in my **app.js**:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = express.Router();
require('./routes/index')(router);
app.use(router);
```

In my **routes/index.js** I have all the routes defined:

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
    });
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
}
```

Then in my app entry point **bin/server.js**:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('NodeJSDemo:server');
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000;
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

When I make a POST call on http://localhost:3000/ with a request body, in the console log console log request body is undefined.

Is there anything wrong with my setup? From this post [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined) it seems as long as I call

> app.use(bodyParser.json())

before loading routes, it should be fine but seems like it does not.

Comment: Try adding this line before app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: No luck :( This should be something trivial, not sure why express does not support them built-in.

Comment: I recommend to generate an express app using express generator, have a look here: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: Actually that is the exact same directory structure I have, the only thing I changes is instead of calling the start script www.js, I renamed to server.js

Comment: How are you making POST requests to your server? Specifically, what are you setting the `Content-Type` to be for those requests? Note that bodyParser doesn't handle requests with `Content-Type` set to `multipart/form-data`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from what type of resource you are sending on your **POST** request.

Your `bodyParser.json()` is ONLY parsing **json** format. Or in other words if you simply POST a simple *form* that in most cases defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you will not get the body object.

As it is stated in the documentation:

> Returns middleware that only parses json and only looks at requests
>   where the Content-Type header matches the type option.

and

> *type* -  The type option is used to determine what media type the middleware
>   will parse. 
>   Defaults to **application/json.**

The solution would be to implement and cather from other scenarios so:

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

**multipart/form-data**

Express does not parse multipart bodies as stated in the documentation:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> 1. **busboy** and **connect-busboy**
> 2. **multiparty** and **connect-multiparty**
> 3. **formidable**
> 4. **multer**

### For Express versions: +4.17.0

You could not include the bodyParser dependency. And use the express built-in methods as:

```
express.json()   
express.text() 
express.urlencoded()
```

They are built based on the bodyParser module so instead calling `bodyParser.json()`. You would do `express.json()` and achieve the same results.

Source:
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions