# NodeJS POST results in undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

All my requests work perfectly except when I try to add an item to an array of json elements, it will return undefined every time.

Controller:

```
    vm.addOptie = function () {
        var newOptie = {"optie": 'stuur',"prijs": 150};
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/addGekozenOptie',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: newOptie
        }).then(function (gekozenOpties) {
            vm.gekozenOpties = gekozenOpties.data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            alert('Er is een fout opgetreden: ' + err);
        })
    }
```

and my router/index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var gekozenOpties = require('../public/data/opties.json');

router.post('/addGekozenOptie', function (req, res) {
    var op = req.body;
    gekozenOpties.push(op);
    res.json(gekozenOpties);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Very frustrating seeing as everything else works fine (get/delete).

Comment: Are you getting `gekozenOpties.data` as `undefined`? It is not clear

Comment: @RaR request.body returns undefined in the router

Comment: did you require('body-parser')?

Comment: Yeah, if I remember correctly you need some middleware for the body parser. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
//install body-parser
npm install body-parser



//Sample code within your app
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

> The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares.
>   All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed
>   body, or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse (or an
>   error was returned).

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much. Can't wait to be done with nodejs/angular and its useless error messages.