# Upload file using multer after specific database operation in node js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using **multer** to upload files via **express**.
Is there a way to perform a database operation before uploading the file?
I need to perform a conditional check whether the user insertion in the database was successful or not depending on that, the file upload should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

To use `multer` as per required you can use the following code:

```
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});
```

`destination` is to specify the path to the directory where uploaded files will be stored.

`filename` is used to determine what the file should be named inside the folder. In this case, we upload the file using a return number value from Date.now() instead of the original name and add a original file extension using the built-in path Node.js library.

```
path.extname(file.originalname);

app.post('/insertUpload', function(req, res) {
    // connection  is db connection variable
    var username = req.body.username;
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', username,
      function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if(!err){ // if not error after insert

          var upload = multer({
             storage: storage
          }).single('userFile')
          upload(req, res, function(err) {
            res.end('File is uploaded')
          });
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: In this line
`var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', username`
I want to access username from `req.body` as it will be coming from the user

Comment: it is just query to insert data into table.. I believe you will replace this with your db query

Comment: I have edited answer, please check. now using req.body.username

Comment: req.body is is always **undefined** before

`upload(req, res, function(err) {
     res.end('File is uploaded') 
})`

Comment: there can be various reasons for req.body as undefined . check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Comment: `bodyParser` cannot parse multipart data. That's the reason req.body is undefined

Comment: No. Before multer upload call, the req.body is always undefined

Comment: Require body-parser (to receive post data from clients)

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json

app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: `body-parser` is unable to handle multipart form data.

Comment: @RyanDsouza what we have to do ?

Comment: @RyanDsouza I prefer multer to handle multipart data.