# req.body.content undefined when trying to create new object for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a simple API to create different objects called entities and store them in a mongo database. I've been following the tutorial [here](https://www.callicoder.com/node-js-express-mongodb-restful-crud-api-tutorial/) and updating it for my own use. I'm using mongoose as well to communicate with the database, but I'm running into an issues where whenever I try and do a POST request, it returns an error due to the fact that req.body.content is undefined. Here is my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create express app
var app = express();

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) );

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

// database requirements
var dbConfig = require( './config/database.config.js' );
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

// Configuring database
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect( dbConfig.url );

mongoose.connection.on( 'error', function()
    {   
        console.log( "Could not connect to the database. Exiting now..." );
        process.exit();
    }   
);

mongoose.connection.once( 'open', function()
    {   
        console.log( "Successfully connected to the database" );
    }   
);

// define a simple route
app.get( '/', function( req, res ) 
    {   
        res.json( { "message" : "Welcome to API. More to come soon...." } );
    }   
);

// Require Entities routes
require( './app/routes/entity.routes.js' )( app );  

// listen for requests
app.listen( 3000, function()
    {   
        console.log( "Server is listening on port 3000" );
    }   
);
```

This is my external `routes.js` file:

```
module.exports = function( app ) { 

   var entities = require( '../controllers/entity.controller.js' );

    // Create a new Entity
    app.post( '/entities', entities.create );

    // Retrieve all Entities
    app.get( '/entities', entities.findAll );

    // Retrieve a single Entity with entityId
    app.get( '/entities/:entityId', entities.findOne );

    // Update an Entity with entityId
    app.put( '/entities/:entityId', entities.update );

    // Delete an Entity with entityId
    app.delete( '/entities/:entityId', entities.delete );

}
```

My `controller.js` file as well:

```
var Entity = require( '../models/entity.model.js' );

exports.create = function( req, res ) 
{

    // create and save a new entity
    console.log( 'req.body: ' + req.body );
    if( !req.body.content ) 
    {   
        console.log( 'req.body.content: ' + req.body.content );

        return res.status( 400 ).send( { message: "Entity can not be empty" } );
    }   

    var entity = new Entity
    ({    
        filename       : req.body.filename, 
        material       : req.body.material,
        design_element : req.body.design_element, 
        style          : req.body.style

    }); 

    entity.save( function( err, data ) 
    {   
        if( err ) 
        {   
            console.log( err );

            res.status( 500 ).send( { message: "Some error occurred while creating the Entity." } );

        }   
        else 
        {   
            res.send( data );
        }   
    }); 

};
```

And an image of my post request as well. I am using Postman to test my request.[image: Post Request Result]

I found some stackoverflow posts already like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined) that says to set any `app.use()` functions before defining any routes, and made sure that body-parser was installed, but I still get the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code where you are attempting this post request?

Comment: I've updated my post to include my post request attempt. I'm using Postman.

Comment: I think Chaim is asking for the code in `entity.routes.js'`

Comment: Gotcha. I've updated the post to include my controller and routes.js code as well.

Comment: in your postman screenshot it seems your sending the response raw, can you try form-url-encoded?

Comment: I think you need to pass your parameter object as ` { content : { filename:  ...} } ` . You are trying to access content from request body which is not there. also then you will need to access other params as `req.body.content.filename` while creating an entity

Comment: @ChaimFriedman I tried doing a form-url-encoded and got the same error stating: "Entity can not be empty"

Comment: ok one final thought. Can you please show what your `console.log(req.body)` prints?

Comment: @HarshalGangurde I put the data inside a content block of the json and got a different error. You can see an image of the error [here](https://imgur.com/a/M1z50)

Comment: @ans maybe try "content" just like other json keys

Comment: @ChaimFriedman Here is a print out of `req.body` and `req.body.content`:
    `Server is listening on port 3000
    Successfully connected to the database
    req.body: [object Object]
    req.body.content: undefined`

Comment: @HarshalGangurde So I did that and strangely it looks like it created an object, but with nothing except an _id and __v value. You can see the post and the result [here](https://imgur.com/a/3mpfY)

Comment: @ans ok so creating a `content` object makes sense if you are passing data the way you were doing it before i.e. `raw` and type of data `JSON` as per screenshots in the question. If you are passing parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded` you don't need to send extra content object as per your latest screenshot. Just pass those four params and may be check for `(!req.body.filename)` to return an error

Comment: @HarshalGangurde Interesting! So it seems that all the fields are blocked out, yet content is undefined, which is why that error get's thrown. You can view the results [here](https://imgur.com/a/do8q6) on the server side. Thank you for the help, I see where my dumb mistake was!!!

Comment: @ans yes exactly. I am not sure what standard you are talking about when you say _accessing through `req.body.content`_. You can access params like `req.body.param` just the way you are doing while creating a new entity. If you want to use `content` object you will have to explicitly pass it in your request

Comment: You can disregard that comment, I was thinking content was set automatically, I see what you mean by having to pass it through explicitly.

Comment: @ans yep, glad that helped