# MEAN Stack: Cannot read property 'companyTitle' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have created a collection in my MongoDB database called `joblist`. I have also created a schema of DB called jobList.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const joblistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyTitle: String,
    jobTitle: String,
    location: String,
});

const JlSchema = module.exports = mongoose.model('JlSchema',joblistSchema,'joblist');
```

This is route folder `users.js` where I'm using my routes

```
const jobList = require('../models/jobList');
//post joblist
router.post('/appliedjobs', function(req,res) {
  console.log('posting');
  jobList.create({
    companyTitle: req.body.companyTitle,
    jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle,
    location: req.body.location
  },function(err,list) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err getting list '+ err);
    } else {
      res.json(list);
    }
  }
  );
});
//getting joblistlist
router.get('/appliedjobs',function(req,res) {
  console.log('getting list');
  jobList.find(function(err,list) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(list);
    }
  });
});
```

I have inserted some data in database manually(by using mongodb cmd).I can get them by `GET` method from

> http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs

but when I'm trying to `post` some data using postman I'm getting error as 
posting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'companyTitle' of undefined
>       at D:\product\project-1\routes\users.js:115:28
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at D:\product\project-1\routes\users.js:15:3
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

I don't know what's wrong in my code. can anyone help? I want get and post data to collection called `joblist`.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'companyType' of undefined` I don't see `companyType` anywhere but the title?

Comment: `body` in `req.body` is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: ya I got it I have just kept the app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); before the routes.

Comment: I don't know what is "router", but I'am sure you forget a return in anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Please test the req.body

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Then in your router

```
router.post('/appliedjobs', function(req,res) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(req.body));

})
```

and in postman set

> "Content-Type"="application/json"

and in body select the type as

> "raw" and "JSON(application/json)"

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the body parser?

This used to be a part of express but now you have to install it separately.

So first install it:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Then require it:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: yes, I've installed it. but I've made extended: false

Comment: I see.. can I see the request body you are including in your post? Are you setting any Content-Type in the request header?

Comment: addJobList(jobitem) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    var selected = {
      companyTitle : jobitem.company,
      jobTitle : jobitem.jobtitle,
      location : jobitem.location
    }
    console.log(selected);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs', JSON.stringify(selected),{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

Comment: There seems to be a ";" instead of "," after the Url.. 'localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs'; <-- ... If that does not help, you can also try to send the payload data without JSON.stringify. So just this.http.post('localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs', selected, {headers: headers})...

Comment: I've posted a question a question on that.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963671/mean-stack-post-method-is-not-reflecting-in-database