# MEAN Stack: post method is not reflecting in database

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, mean-stack

I'm trying to pass some data through HTTP post method but it is not reflecting in the database.
This is code.

```
addJobList(jobitem) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    var selected = {
      companyTitle : jobitem.company,
      jobTitle : jobitem.jobtitle,
      location : jobitem.location
    }
    console.log(selected);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs', JSON.stringify(selected),{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
//getting jobs form back-end
  getAppliedjobList() {
    if (this.jobslist) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.jobslist);
    }
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs',{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.jobslist = data;
        resolve(this.jobslist);
      });
    });
  }
```

I've data in in the object called selected.

```
{companyTitle: "Facebook", jobTitle: "System Engineer", location: "torinto,canada"}
```

data from console. But this data is not get inserted into the database.
This is the code in my routes folder.

```
const jobList = require('../models/jobList');
router.post('/appliedjobs', function(req,res) {
  console.log('posting');
  jobList.create({
    companyTitle: req.body.companyTitle,
    jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle,
    location: req.body.location
  },function(err,list) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err getting list '+ err);
    } else {
      res.json(list);
    }
  }
  );
});
```

I'm not getting any error just the data is not getting inserted into the database.
This is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const joblistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyTitle: String,
    jobTitle: String,
    location: String,
});

const JlSchema = module.exports = mongoose.model('JlSchema',joblistSchema,'joblist');
```

Comment: Are you using mongo? In you jobList model try setting var mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.set('debug', true); and see if you get anything in the console.

Comment: Don't stringify before sending `this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs', selected,{headers})`

Comment: yes I've tried no use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to encode your data like in this [example](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/#_post_with_data) and you must return your this.http.post.

```
addJobList(jobitem) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    const selected = {
      companyTitle : jobitem.company,
      jobTitle : jobitem.jobtitle,
      location : jobitem.location
    }
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs', selected, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

To use it you need to subscribe to your addJobList method, http.post is an observable and needs to be subscribed to make the http call :

```
addJobList(theJobItem).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```