# Why my Ajax object comes back as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I'm trying to make an Ajax request, but my object keeps coming back as undefined.

Here's my client side code:

```
<a class="clicklink" href="/bookDetails"><h5 class="card-title"><%= title %></h5></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".card-title").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      contentType: "application/json; harset=UTF-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({ID:'<%= ID %>'}),
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/bookDetails',
      success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my post request code:

```
router.post('/bookDetails', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.ID);
});
```

BTW, I'm putting my `<h5>` tag inside a link so it's clickable. I don't maybe that's the problem but I don't think so. But this is the error I get back:

> Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but in the `contentType` field you're missing the 'c' in 'charset'

Comment: @pfcodes I fixed it. But that wasn't the problem lol

Comment: Did you try adding a fail: function(data) and look at the data object for a clue to what was happening?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: @BlackICE Got it. I put the config for body-parser in my routes folder when i should have put it in index.js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Express, make sure you have the `body-parser` middleware enabled.

Related Post: [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the property cannot be read because the parent is undefined. One common cause of this is that the response from the ajax call is a string rather than an object. Have you checked the return type?

Comment: I didn't have my configuration right but I resolved the issue already. Thanks though.