# TypeError: Cannot read property email of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm still trying to understand routing in node.js,
Other routes like route.get(all) and  single id are working perfectly, but "router.post" is giving an error in postman such as **"TypeError: Cannot read property email  of undefined"**;

For the index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const redflags_table = require('../db/redflags_table');
const router = express.Router();


router.put('/api/v1/redflag/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
  let recordFound;
  let itemIndex;
  redflags_table.map((record, index) => {
    if (record.id === id) {
      recordFound = record;
      itemIndex = index;
    }
  });

  if (!recordFound) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      success: 'false',
      message: 'todo not found',
    });
  }

  if (!req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      success: 'false',
      message: 'title is required',
    });
  }
  const updatedRedflag = {
    id: recordFound.id,
    email: req.body.email || recordFound.email
  };

  redflags_table.splice(itemIndex, 1, updatedRedflag);

  return res.status(201).send({
    success: 'true',
    message: 'todo added successfully',
    updatedRedflag,
  });
});
```

The app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const router = require('./routes/index.js');

app.use(router);



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Is it "PUT" or "POST"?

Comment: can you post our postman request? If express handles JSON something like: (`curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"value"}' "/api/v1/redflag/1"`) -v

Comment: `redflags_table.map` That is the wrong way to find an element in an array.

Comment: Is it req.body or is it recordFound that is undefined?

Comment: it is PUT @ChrisG

Comment: @epascarello  req,body it is, which is req.body.email

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrage the order of your middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const router = require('./routes/index.js');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(router);
```

Comment: oh good, glad it worked. Can you select it as your "answer" so I can get some points :-)

Comment: yea i just did that :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2021**

Now `body-parser` is deprecated, you can use `express`:

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

app.use(express.json({limit: '20mb'}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '20mb' }))

export default app
```

Comment: Thanks' this work's for me, i have 1 question! why limit: 20 ?? can you explain me this or give me a good url news!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose then it can be solved by fixing options .like this mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

Hopefully your problem will be sorted .

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with these simple steps.

install body parser for  content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
1) npm i --save body-parser
```

2)go into your root file in your case it is index.js add these lines of code **before routes**.

```
//require body-parser

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```