# express router, req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, express, router

I have a post interface that does not submit data correctly.
test shows:  req.body undefined

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const passportInfo = passport.authenticate('jwt',{ session: false });
const HomeSchema = require('../../../models/AnvizHome');
const homeBannerValidator = require('../../../validation/anviz/homeBanner');

router.post("/banner",passportInfo,(req,res) => {

const {msg,isValid} = homeBannerValidator(req.body);
if(!isValid){
    return res.status(400).json(msg);
}

HomeSchema.findOne({handle:req.body.handle}).then(banner => {
  console.log('current:   ' + req.body);
    const newBanner = {
        bannerBg:req.body.bannerBg,
        bannerName:req.body.bannerName,
        bannerSubName:req.body.bannerSubName,
        bannerFeather:req.body.bannerFeather,
        bannerLink:req.body.bannerLink
  };
  banner.prodcutBanner = newBanner;
  banner.then(home => res.json(home));
})
.catch((err) => res.json(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

postman test:
[image]

In fact, the terminal can see the returned data.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
   bannerBg: '5555555555555555555555555555555555',
   bannerName: 'THE GLOBAL LEADING',
   bannerSubName: 'PROVIDER OF INTELLIGENT SECURITY',
   bannerLink: 'www.anviz.com',
   handle: 'true' }
```

Seeking one or two！Thank you！

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to import and use body parser 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
express.use(bodyParser.json());
express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: I have loaded body-parser but it's useless.

Comment: const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const app = express();

Comment: wirte these two line too

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the reason, because this is based on the user's token to submit data, so must be in the post according to the user id to determine whether the data is successful?

Here is the code that has been successfully saved, but I don't know right and wrong:

```
router.post("/banner",passportInfo,(req,res) => {

const {msg,isValid} = homeBannerValidator(req.body);
if(!isValid){
    return res.status(400).json(msg);
}

const profileFields = {};
profileFields.prodcutBanner = {};
if(req.body.handle) profileFields.handle = req.body.handle;
if(req.body.bannerBg) profileFields.prodcutBanner.bannerBg = req.body.bannerBg;
if(req.body.bannerName) profileFields.prodcutBanner.bannerName = req.body.bannerName;
if(req.body.bannerSubName) profileFields.prodcutBanner.bannerSubName = req.body.bannerSubName;
if(req.body.bannerFeather) profileFields.prodcutBanner.bannerFeather = req.body.bannerFeather;
if(req.body.bannerLink) profileFields.prodcutBanner.bannerLink = req.body.bannerLink;


HomeSchema.findOne({user: req.user.id}).then(profile => {
  if(profile){
    HomeSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({user: req.user.id},{$set:profileFields},{new:true}).then(profile => res.json(profile));
  }else{
    HomeSchema.findOne({handle:profileFields.handle}).then(profile => {
        if(profile){
            msg.handle = "The user's handle personal information already exists, please do not re-create it!";
            res.status(400).json(msg);
        }
        new HomeSchema(profileFields).save().then(profile => res.json(profile));
    })
  }
})
.catch((err) => res.json(err));});


module.exports = router;
```