# Uploading Image to Cloudinary Express.js React Axios post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images to cloudinary using react front-end and express server.
The problem is i cant properly post request image to my  express server.

This is how i prepare image to send it later:

```
          var data = new FormData();
          console.log(event.target.files[0]) // this prints FileObject succesfully
          data.append('image', event.target.files[0]);
         console.log(data) // this prints {} but i guess its natural since its FormData ??
          this.imageToUpload = data;
```

This is how i post request:

```
 axios.post('/api/courses/uploadImage',this.imageToUpload, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }

    })
    .then( (response) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));


    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Now in server side,`req.body` is empty.

```
router.post("/courses/uploadImage",(req,res,next)=>{

    console.log(req.body) // empty
    var image = req.body;
   cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, function(error, result) { console.log(result) });


  })
```

Also what should i really put to first parameter of(image in this case) `uploader.upload` ?

Comment: Did you try using req.file.path in uploader.upload? Using body-parser might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Comment: req.file is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by directly uploading images to cloudinary from client with their html5 codepen example.

Comment: please share the link

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but if you want Cloudinary also offers a way to directly upload images from your front-end so it saves you some work. You can [read here further](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_image_and_video_upload).

I've worked with their widget and it is very simple to integrate into almost any app.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. I have successfully tried in my project.

```
function upload(){
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', event.target.files[0]);
  data.append('username', 'Saurabh'); //if you have other fields

  axios.post('/api/courses/uploadImage', data,
   headers: {
    //your headers
   })
  .then( (response) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
  });
}
```

In your express route you can simply get values like this

```
router.post('/api/courses/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), async(req,res, next) => {

 const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
 console.log(req.body.username); //Saurabh

 //your logic

});
```