# Node/Express not seeing my data posted from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

Server API is Node / Express 4.17, client is Angular 8.

I have a data model in Angular:

```
export class myData
{ ... }
```

UI Component .ts uses it:

```
import { myData } from 'mydata';
...
const md: myData = new myData();
// populate md
this.myService.addData(md);
```

myservice.ts:

```
import { myData } from 'mydata';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
...
export class myService{
  constructor(private http: httpClient) {}
  addData(mymd: myData)
  {
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, mymd);
    this.http.request(req).subscribe(something => {});
  }
}
```

Node/Express server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
server.post('/api', async function v1(req, res)
{
  let x = req.body;
  ...
}
```

Fiddler shows `md` and its content submitted but `req` has no `body`, nor `md` or any user data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use body-parser to parse body in Express.

Try to use that.

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var server = express()

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
server.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

server.post('/api', async function v1(req, res)
{
  let x = req.body;
  ...
}
```

Comment: req.body is undefined.

Comment: This article may help you in case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined

Comment: besides `body-parser`, it's the sequence, your above link solved the last piece of the puzzle. Will be great if you can update your post, I will check it as solution if so. Thank you very much for your help!