# React.js, Node.js : send axios request in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I try to send a request with an email and a password with axios in react.`
React app:

```
      console.log(`
    --SUBMITTING--
    First Name: ${this.state.firstName}
    Last Name: ${this.state.lastName}
    Email: ${this.state.email}
    Password: ${this.state.password}
  `);
  this.sendData(this.state.email, this.state.password);
  // this.changeRoot("calendar");
} else {
  console.error("FORM INVALID - DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE");
}
```

};

```
  sendData(login, password) {
console.log("login -> " + login);
console.log("passwor -> " + password);
axios.post('http://localhost:9000/signup', { email: login, psswd: password })
.then((rep) => { console.log(rep) })
.catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
```

}

The data in login and password are OK.
Node server :

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
console.log("login -> " + req.body.email);
console.log("psswd -> " + req.body.psswd);
```

});

So thank for all help.

Comment: May I know what is the issue/error you are facing?

Comment: i have an error 500. and error like this in my terminal.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
at /home/clementbl/Tek1/My_Project/Blooprint/blooprint/api/server.js:20:40
at Layer.handle [as handle_request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, but, it looks like you are not configuring the bodyParser() middleware (the one that parses data from the HTTP request into the `req.body`)

Please see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855234/79536)