# nodejs express req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, express, undefined

I write this code and req.body is undefined
I want to get post value in my program 
can you help me, please?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const crypto = require('crypto');
function sha1(s) {
    return crypto.createHash("sha1")
        .update(s)
        .digest("hex");
}
app.post("/flag", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: add this line before post `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: no
just return " {} " in console

(sorry for loooooong time delay)

Answer (score 2):

You **body-parser** npm package

```
$ npm i body-parser
```

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const crypto = require('crypto');

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

function sha1(s) {
    return crypto.createHash("sha1")
        .update(s)
        .digest("hex");
}
app.post("/flag", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: Body-parser has been obsoleted for a year or so.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using body parser, Express already providing support for that,

```
import express from "express";  
const app = express(); 

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

This should be given before the Api route