# How can I get data passed from axios post request through to nuxt serverMiddleware?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to pass some data to my serverMiddleware using axios but I can't seem to be able to get the data in my serverMiddleware

`guilds` page script:

```js
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    const token = 'testToken'
    const guilds = await this.$axios.$post('/api/guilds', { token })
  }
}
</script>
```

serverMiddleware:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

const app = express()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
})

export default {
  path: '/api/guilds',
  handler: router
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token should be an object of key-value.

```
 async fetch() {
   const token = 'testToken'
   const guilds = await this.$axios.$post('/api/guilds', { token: token })
 }
```

Then you can take it from `req.body` in serverMiddleware.

Comment: `req.body` is returning `undefined`

Comment: add `express.bodyParser()` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined