# Not able to take inputs from HTML form with Node Js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend

I am trying to receive an input from an html form in my js file.

**HTML**

```
<form action='/bmicalc' method="post">
      <input type='text' name='h' placeholder='Height'>
      <input type='text' name='w' placeholder='Weight'>
      <button type='submit' name='sub'>Calculate</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello There!<h1>');
});

app.get('/bmicalc',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/bmicalc.html');
})

app.post('/bmicalc',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.h);
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Started server on port 3000");
})
```

However I'm always getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'h' of undefined

Can someone please help point out the mistake?

Comment: It seems the `req.body` is `undefined`. So that's why you cannot access the property `h`.

Comment: But I have form tag within the html body tag. So why should it show undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

The [Express API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) makes the following statement clear (emphasis mine):

> ### req.body
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use
> body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or
> `express.urlencoded()`.**

The code sample you posted does not make use of the middlewares the documentation makes reference to. You can leverage `app.use()` to enable them:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello There!<h1>');
});

app.get('/bmicalc',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/bmicalc.html');
})

app.post('/bmicalc',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.h);
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Started server on port 3000");
})
```

Comment: Thanks  really, wasn't aware of this.

Comment: According to Mark Bonano: 
Express doesn't have body-parsing anymore

More information here: (as of 2020) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined?rq=1