# The 'req.body' on Express.js v^4.17.1 returns 'undefined' from post requests

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, router

I've been trying to get something to send to my shoutbox_endpoint, but on the Express.JS Backend where the endpoint is it returns `req.body` as `undefined`

### Post Request

```js
const headers = {
    "SMN-Auth-JWT": " REDACTED "
};

axios.post(this.endpoint_shoutbox, {
    headers: headers,
    data: {
        user: who,
        message: message,
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

### Backend Endpoint

```js
router.post('/shoutbox-relay', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params); // {} 
    console.log(req.query); // {}
    console.log(req.body); // Undefined   
});
```

### Main.js

```js
const Logger = require("./LogHandler");
const config = require("../Settings/conf.json");
const Path = require("path");
const ExpressJS = require("express");
const Router = require("./RouterHandler");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = ExpressJS();

module.exports.start = async (client) => {
    try {
        app.set("view engine", "ejs");
        app.use("/assets", ExpressJS.static(Path.join(__dirname, "../Website/assets")));
        app.use("/socket.io", ExpressJS.static(Path.join(__dirname, "../Website/assets/socket.io")));
        app.set("views", Path.join(__dirname, "../Website/views"));

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.disable("x-powered-by");
    
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            req.bot = client;
            next();
        });
        app.use("/", Router.index);
        app.use("/about", Router.about);
        app.use("/chat", Router.chat);
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            var err = new Error("File Not Found");
            err.status = 404;
            next();
        });

        const Listener = http.listen(config.Website.port, function () {
            Logger.log("Website Handler", "Webserver Started.");
        });
    } catch (err) {
        Logger.error("Website Handler", `Webserver failed to load due to: ${err}`);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you use `body-parser`?

Comment: Smh... are you kidding me... if this is the answer i'm gonna be embarrassed xD

Comment: @Anatoly Unfortunately even with body-parser it does the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to take inputs from HTML form with Node Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145324/not-able-to-take-inputs-from-html-form-with-node-js)

Comment: If it is the case that `body-parser` also didn't help, can you provide the updated script to show how you've used it?

Comment: @esqew I have provided the main.js file that links to the router I'm using for this `req.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One observation is that, DATA on the client-side JavaScript isn't JSON-stringified.  And I would prefer mentioning contentType: 'application/json'

Here is a sample at my end, that's working well with pretty much your configuration.

***Client-side JS:***

```
function saveBankDetails() {
    someDetails =  { bankDetails: {
        someKey1:   "SOME VALUE 1,
        someKey2: "SOME VALUE 2"
     }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: ("SOME PATH"),
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(someDetails),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jXhr) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jXhr) {
        console.log('failure')
        console.log(jXhr)
    });    

}
```

***Server-side code:***

```
router.post('SOME PATH', async (req,  res) {
    console.log(req.body.bankDetails)
});
```

***Output:***

```
 {
        someKey1:   "SOME VALUE 1,
        someKey2: "SOME VALUE 2"
 }
```