# Form in html nodejs returns undefined after receiving post request

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I did in HTML a `<form></form>` object which should return a username, a email and a password, but for some reason it returns `undefined` if I do `req.body.name` or anything else and it just won't work and idk why

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 400px; text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;" class="card">
    <h1 class="loginTitle card-title" style="margin-top: 10px;">Register</h1>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/register" method="POST">

            <div>
                <label class="loginLabel" for="name">Username: </label>
                <input style="margin-left: 68px;" class="loginInput" id="name" name="name" required type="text">
            </div>
    
            <div>
                <label class="loginLabel" for="email">Email: </label>
                <input style="margin-left: 110px;" class="loginInput" id="email" name="email" required type="email">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label class="loginLabel" for="password">Password: </label>
                <input style="margin-left: 76px;" class="loginInput" id="password" name="password" required type="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;">Register</button>
        </form>
        <a href="/login" style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: orange; font-size: 19px; margin-top: -10px;">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my NodeJS code:

```
website.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    var usersReg = []
    try {
        const hashedPw = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        usersReg.push({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPw
        })
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
    catch {
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
    console.log(usersReg)
})
```

Please help me - I don't understand where the error is coming from.

(If I don't do catch it says just that the `bcrypt.hash()` method needs a string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are not probably using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). You should use the middleware in your server entry point to parse the body of the requests.
Also, your question is duplicated and you can find the complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined).

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```