# req.body & req.params.id undefined (PUT & PATCH)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the `express.json()` before the `app.patch` but both `req.body & req.params.id` return undefined. I've tried to change the route to `/:id` but it didn't work. It works for `app.get` and `app.post`.

Headers: `Content-Type: application/json`

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config({ path: ".env" });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
    
app.patch("/api/v1/", (res, req, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: Is there a reason you NEED to use patch? I understand the urge to use these fancy new HTTP VERBS, but that's just it, they don't necessarily add much besides nice verbage.

Comment: @callback I'm using Express 4 which has build-in body parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it mixed up.

`req` comes before `res`.

```
app.patch("/api/v1/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Also, make sure you add a `/` before `api`.