# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting the following error when trying to handle `post` requests:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. This is my code:

```js
router.post("/", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { post, newTags } = req.body;
    console.log("my body!", req.body);
    
    post.fullName = req.user.fullName;
    post.UserId = req.user.id;
    await Posts.create(post);
      
    newTags.forEach((tag) => {
        tagPost(tag, id);
    });
    
    res.json(post);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show result of `console.log("my body!", req.body);`

Comment: Do you have any bodyparsing middleware? If yes are you sure your `body` does in fact have a `newTags` property? Seems it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: Yeah her it is...........
my body! {
  postText: 'Another data type is the Boolean. Booleans may only be one of two values: true or false. They are basically little on-off switches, where true is on and false 
is off. These two states are mutually exclusive. c\n' +
    '\n',
  postTitle: 'In HTML and css'
}

Comment: there is no `newTags` property in the body you posted in the comment. Only `postText` and `postTitle` ... So obviously `newTags` will be undefined after deconstructing the body ... Which makes me wonder why `post.fullName` doesn't throw an error, because `post` will also be undefined

Comment: Yeah bro I found the error it was some issue on the client-side:

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Content-Type: application/json` to POST data, make sure to add parser middleware. You can use `body-parser` in your API router by installing it with `npm install body-parser` and implementing it with lines bellow:

```
const body-pareser = require('body-parser');
// your router init, etc...
router.use(body-parser.json());
// your routes, middlewares, whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://expressjs.com/it/api.html#req.body), `req.body` is `undefined` by default. You have to implement a body-parsing middleware to have it populated.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined) is a very similar question (if not identical). Please make some research before asking.

Comment: if `body` was `undefined`, an error would be thrown already at `const { post, newTags } = req.body;` because you cannot deconstruct an `undefined`.  It's more likely, that there is a `body` (and it's also parsed), but it doesn't contain a `newTags` property`

Comment: @derpirscher you are right, didn't notice the deconstruction.