# { "error": "Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'req.body' as it is undefined." }

Tags: node.js, express, mern, destructor

following are the code snippets for a Node.js application:

```
// src/models/workoutsModel.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const workoutSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String, // Corrected to String
    required: true,
  },
  reps: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  load: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("workout", workoutSchema);

// src/Routes/workout.js
const express = require("express");
const Workout = require("../Model/workoutsModel");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "route for all workouts" });
});

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "getting single routes",
  });
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, reps, load } = req.body;
    const workout = await Workout.create({ title, reps, load });
    res.status(200).json(workout);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "deleting workouts",
  });
});

router.patch("/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "updating workouts",
  });
});

module.exports = router;

// sr/server.js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const workoutRoutes = require("./Routes/workouts");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "you are on the root page" });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path, req.method);
  next();
});

app.use("/api/workouts", workoutRoutes);

app.use(express.json());

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.URI)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(
        "connected to the database and listening on port",
        process.env.PORT
      );
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("error connecting to the database");
  });
```

Can anyone please offer me some help here? Currently, I am trying to work with **express.json()**, but it does not seem to be working as expected when I attempt to destructure the request body. I'm encountering an issue, and I'm unsure how to resolve it. If anyone has experience or insights into using **express.json()** with destructuring and can provide some guidance or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js req.body undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined)

Comment: Please edit the post to format the code you provided https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body parsing middleware is inserted after some of the routes, so those earlier routes won't see any parsed body.

Make sure your `express.json()` middleware is installed *above* your `workoutRoutes`.